# figuring out the algebraic expression for an algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the following algorithm:

```
 count = 0
 for i= 1 to n:
      for j= i+1 to n:
           for k= i+1 to j:
                count += 1
```

How can we deduce the algebraic expression to determine the value of count?

Comment: I wasn't aware that "we" is a synonym of "you, because I can't be bothered"... at least, at MSE. But then, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=i+1}^{j}1
&=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} (j-i)
\\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j
-
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Deal with the parts separately.

For the first part:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(
\sum_{j=1}^{n} j
-
\sum_{j=1}^{i} j
\right)
\\
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
-
\frac{i(i+1)}{2}
\right)
\\
&= 
\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}
-
\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\frac{i(i+1)}{2}
\\
&= 
\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}
-
\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}  i^2
-
\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i
\\
&= 
\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}
-
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}
-
\frac{n(n+1)}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the second part:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} 1
&=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i (n-i)
\\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} ni -i^2
\\
&=
n \sum_{i=1}^{n} i 
-
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2
\\
&=
\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}
-
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

Subtracting the second part from the first should give the required result. I therefore make it
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}
-
\frac{n(n+1)}{4} 
&=
\frac{n(n+1)}{4}
\left(
\frac{2n+1}{3} - 1
\right)
\\
&=
\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

In Python, the expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=i+1}^{j}1
$$
can be implemented as a function using loops as follows:

```
def get_count(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(i+1,n+1):
            for k in range(i+1, j+1):
                count += 1
    return count
```

Recalling that the `range` function is inclusive for the first argument and exclusive for the second.

Comment: doesn't match for the programmatic value of  n=10, which is 120 but from the formula gives 165

Comment: The difference between the value you obtained and the value given by the formula is due to whether n is included in the summation or not. If you evaluate the above formula for $n=9$ it will match your value. I can include some Python code that illustrates this point if you like. Moreover, if you replace $n$ with $n-1$ in my formula, you will obtain the formula that you guessed at.

Comment: @lind https://ideone.com/Ewlci0 there are 165.

Comment: @aid78 , please see this: https://repl.it/repls/TreasuredQueasyPaddlefish

Comment: @Paul Aljabar, yes please, some python code with make a better understanding.

Comment: Okay done. Please see above and check how the Python `range` function is used.

Comment: @PaulAljabar, Wow, By far the most best explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^j 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n j-i = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{t=1}^{n-i} t = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} T(n-i) = \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} T(s) =\sum_{s=1}^{n-1} \binom{s+1}{2}$$
$$ = \sum_{s=2}^{n} \binom{s}{2} =  \binom{n+1}{3}$$

Note that when $i=n$ the cycle immediatelly terminates as $j=n+1 > n$, so that's why the first sum runs from $1$ to $n-1$. Also $T(n)$ is the triangle number and by the Gauss' Trick we know that $T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2}$. For the final equality we used the identity:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{i}{j} = \binom{n+1}{j+1}$$

Comment: @aid78 I explained in the paragraph afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The innermost loop runs exactly $j-(i+1)+1$ times, and its effect is to add $j-i$ to $\text{count}$.

The intermediate loop invokes the inner loop with increasing values of $j$ (from $i+1$ to $n$), thus adds $1+2+\cdots... n-i$ to $\text{count}$, or $\dfrac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}2$.

The outer loop invokes the intermediate loop with $i$ from $1$ to $n$, so that the final value of $\text{count}$ is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}2.$$

Comment: this is not in terms of n, so, how do we plug in n to get the result of count?

Comment: @lind: this *is* in terms of $n$ ($i$ is a dummy index). You can further simplify by means of the triangular and pyramidal numbers, but the above expression does give the final value of $\text{count}$.

Comment: That is if we expand the sum.

Comment: I mean a more compact formula, um, without the dummy variable.

Comment: @lind: I gave you the hint. This is another exercise.

Comment: well.... I've been trying. :_)

Comment: I made a lucky guess, it is: n(n-1)(n-2)/6. Don't know how I got it.

Comment: @lind: check with a few (small) values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=i+1}^{j}1= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(j-i)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{jj=1}^{n-i}(jj)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n-i+1)(n-i)}{2}=$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}(1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+...+(n-2)(n-1)+(n-1)n)$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer of n(n-1)(n+1)/6 is correct for the algorithm with for loops as stated in the question.

Some of the confusion has been due to people incorrectly translating the algorithm to python using range statements which omit the final value of the range (and also start from zero if the start of the range is not specified).